# PHP connection to MySql error reporting

Tags: php, mysqli

This seems to be very simple but I am having trouble with this php error reporting. I am trying to connect to a DB and if the connection fails I want to report a simple message e.g "Connection to db failed". But using the code below I get those php warning messages. How can I display only the user friendly message?  Thanks guys

```
 function mySqlConnection($host, $username, $pass, $dbname){

 $connection = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $pass, $dbname)
 or die ('Connection to db failed');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prefix the function with an `@` to suppress the warnings.

```
function mySqlConnection($host, $username, $pass, $dbname){
 $connection = @mysqli_connect($host, $username, $pass, $dbname)
 or die ('Connection to db failed');
}
```

You can also use `ini_set('display_errors','0');` which will suppress *all* warnings and errors though, this is probably not what you want. (It can get annoying later when debugging)

In production you should disable the error display though and log them to a file.

Comment: This answer contradicts with itself

Comment: but it works... the @ at the begin of the mysqli_connect does remove the warning messages.

Comment: it doesn't. you don't need to gag error message while debugging, yet you will turn off displaying errors on production anyway.

Comment: @YourCommonSense There's a difference between production and debug mode. While debugging, you want to see all warnings and errors (suppressing this one will still show an error `Connection to db failed`). In production mode, you want to disable all error display and log them to a file, imo this should be done in the web server config though.

Comment: @YourCommonSense That's up to the dev. You could put anything there. But we're getting offtopic here. OP wanted a solution to suppress the warnings and errors and show `Connection to db failed` instead, and that's the solution to the question.

Comment: @YourCommonSense this is just a University course work and the Connection to db failed is just an example of message. It does not matter if it makes sense or not. This is just an example used to formulate the question. This solution is valid for the purpose of my question. Take it easy!

Answer (score 1):

A user have no idea what a DB is and what to do if it's failed.

For ALL errors may occur in your code, you have to show only a generalized error page, along with sending an **appropriate HTTP code**.

So, make it this way.

```
set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    error_log("$errstr in $errfile:$errline");
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error', TRUE, 500);
    readfile("500.html");
    exit;
}

function mySqlConnection($host, $username, $pass, $dbname)
{
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $connection = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $pass, $dbname);
}
```

where 500.html is your user-friendly error page

Comment: In production mode, your web server should be configured to throw a 500 when a PHP error happens anyway. When debugging this can get really annoying though.

Answer (score 0):

```
$link=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");

mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())

  {

  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();

  }
```